# How to calculate the matrix element of a coupling item under an uncoupled representation in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider two particles with charges in a column field, where the Hamilton of the system is $$H=H_1+H_2+4a(\bf{L_1}\cdot\bf{L_2})^2.$$
($H_1,H_2$ represent the Hamilton of particles $1$ and $2$ respectively, i.e.$H_i=\frac{p_i^2}{2m}-\frac{Z_0Z_ie^2}{r_i}$, and $\bf{L_1}$,$\bf{L_2}$ represent the angular monument of particle $1$ and $2$.)

Let $|{\alpha_i}\rangle=|{n_il_im_i}\rangle$ as "the uncoupled representation" and treat $H'=4a(\bf{L_1}\cdot\bf{L_2})^2$ as a perturbation. When I attempted to calculate the matrix element of it under the $\alpha$ representation, i.e.
$$\langle\alpha_1',\alpha_2'|H'|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle=4a\langle\alpha_1',\alpha_2'|(L_{1x}L_{2x}+L_{1y}L_{2y}+L_{1z}L_{2z})^2|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle,$$
I found it hard because items like $\langle\alpha_i'|(L_{ix})^2|\alpha_i\rangle$ and $\langle\alpha_i'|(L_{ix}L_{iy})|\alpha_i\rangle$ trouble me. You might tell me to replace $L_x$ and $L_y$ by $L_\pm$, but it seems not that easy to apply $[L_z,L_\pm]=\pm\hbar L_\pm$ further to the calculation since there is somewhat like $\langle\alpha_i'|(L_{i\pm})^2|\alpha_i\rangle$ and $\langle\alpha_i'|(L_{i\pm}L_{i\mp})|\alpha_i\rangle$. Or are there other methods?

Could anyone help me? A derivation as detailed as possible would be appreciated.

Comment: "As detailed as possible" is not likely to convince *anyone* that you are not, in fact, asking someone to ***do your homework for you***.

Comment: @CosmasZachos This is not my homework.

Comment: If anyone could lead me a way clearly in a few words, detailed derivation is surely useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not explain *why* you rejected the fundamental underlying identity
$$
{\mathbf L^1}\cdot {\mathbf L^2}=\frac{L_+^1 L_-^2 + L_-^1L_+^2}{2}+ L_z^1 L_z^2,
$$
whose action on the uncoupled basis states is self-evident.

Comment: I am sorry...I forgot that for $L_\pm$ we simply have $$L_\pm\ket{\alpha}=A_l^m\ket{\alpha^{m\pm1}}$$. I thought $$[L_z,L_\pm]=\pm\hbar L\pm$$ must be used which might fail encountering $L_\pm^2$.